# Non-isomorphic non-hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have the following question:

> Find an infinite family of non-isomorphic graphs without hamiltonian paths such that $\delta(u) + \delta(v) \geq |V(G)| - 2$ for every non adjacent vertices $u, v$.

I'm new in these topics, so I don't know where to start. Can somebody give me a hint or some help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know where to start? Start by finding **one** graph which satisfies those conditions. Then find another one. After you have found a few different ones, try to generalize. What examples have you found so far?

Comment: I don't see where it says the graphs have to be connected. So why don't you take the union of two disjoint copies of the complete graph $K_n$? By varying $n$ you will get nonisomorphic graphs.